# Unknown opcode skipped: 62, not 8086 instruction - not supported yet

Tags: assembly, x86

I'm using emu 8086 for a certain project, when I create "mensaje 2 dw" I get this error "Unknown opcode skipped: 62, not 8086 instruction - not supported yet", it doesn't make sense I get such an error at the beginning of the code...

PD: I'm missing print functions, will fix when I figure out why i'm having this error lol.

```
name proyecto
org 100h 
caso dw 0
x dw 0
y dw 0
a dw 1
p dw 0
b dw 1
seed dw 1
mensaje1 dw 'Ostacle is in the position [ $'
mensaje2 dw 'Object is in the position [ $'
mensaje3 dw 'Object moved to [ $'
mensaje4 dw ' with an angle of $'
mensaje41 dw 'grades$'
mensaje5 dw 'Returned to its normal way in the position [ $' 
        ; Pseudo random number x = (seed*4 + 99) % 6;
        jmp random
        random :
        mov ax, seed
            mov cx, 4
            mul cx
        ; x = seed*4
        mov x,ax
        mov ax,x
        add ax,99
        ; x = x+c
        mov x,ax
        mov ax,x
        mov cx,6
        div cx
        ; x = x%6
        mov x,dx
        mov y,dx
        mov ax,seed
        ; Add one to seed to generate a different number next time
        add ax,1
        mov seed,ax
        ; Add generated number to the actual position of the object
        mov ax, x
        add ax, a
        mov x, ax
        mov ax, y
        add ax, b
        mov y, ax
        cmp ax, 15
        ; *Print position of the obstacle, i'm missing some stuff here*

        lea dx,mensaje1
        mov ah,09h
        int 21h


        jmp recorrido
        recorrido :
        ; Object will move until position 15
            mov ax, a
            cmp ax, 15
            ja fin
            cmp caso, 1
            je cumple
            mov ax, a
            jmp comparar_x
        ; If actual position is equal to obstacle position the object will move
            comparar_x :

        mov ax, a
        add ax, 1
        mov a, ax
        mov cx, b
        add cx, 1
        mov b, cx
        mov bx, x
        cmp bx, ax
        jz comparar_y
        ja resultado_zero
        jb resultado_zero

        comparar_y :
        mov bx, y
            cmp bx, cx
            jz resultado
            ja resultado_zero
            jb resultado_zero

            resultado :
            mov caso, 1
            jmp recorrido

            resultado_zero :
            mov caso, 0
            jmp recorrido

            cumple :
            ; Moves object
            mov cx, b
            add cx, 1
            mov b, cx      



        jmp producto_escalar

        jmp recorrido
        producto_escalar :
        ; Producto escalar(a, b) and (a - 1, b - 2)
        ; Operation between the position before and after moving
            mov cx, a
            dec cx
            mov ax, x
            mul cx
            mov p, ax
            mov ax, b
            mov cx, y
            sub cx, 1
            mul cx
            add p, ax
            mov caso, 0
        ; Angle = ( producto escalar * 10 ) % 360
        mov cx, 10
        mov ax, p
        mul cx
        mov p, ax
        mov ax, p
        mov cx, 360
        div cx
        mov p, dx
        ;Object returns to its normal course (y=x)
        jmp continuar
        continuar :
        mov ax, a
            add ax, 1
            mov a, ax
            mov b, ax

        mov ax, a
        cmp ax, 15
        jz fin
        ja fin
        jb random
        fin :
ret
```

Comment: Execution starts at the top of your file because this is a .com executable so it can't have separate code/data sections, and you didn't try to declare any anyway.  You put data there, but the (virtual) CPU decodes that as instruction bytes.

Comment: @PeterCordes I still don't understand how can I solve the problem

Comment: put your data at the end.

Comment: `org 100h 
jmp random
caso dw 0`

(...)

Like this?

Comment: It also compiled when i put it after the ret, the hell... and before too

Comment: There are big differences between "it compiles/assembles", "it runs", "it runs without a crash" and "it runs and does what I expect". Your original code should assemble, but fail at runtime.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis yeah, i realized as long as i could compile the code, it does nothing :/ any idea why? This is my first program in assembly so far and I'm lost

Comment: Your program starts at the start. But the first bytes of the program are not runnable opcodes at all, they are data, containing who-knows-what. So either put a `jmp random` ***at the very start***, i.e. directly after the `org 0100h` and before the first `dw` (i.e. not where you put it) that jumps over that data, or put the data after the runnable code. The latter is the better option, IMO. This is a simple .com program, so it does not have separate data and code segments. It is really loaded and starts at offset 0100h. The first bytes must be runnable code, not data.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis hey, i tried to put the data just after the "jmp random" and also tried the latter option you mentioned just before the "ret", it compiles but it does nothing, any idea why? I originally made this code in visual studio with the _asm , with the data declared as short and the print functions of C it worked perfectly but now it does nothing so i guess the issue is when im going to print... i think it should at least print the first message :/

Comment: **After** the `ret`. The `ret` is also runnnable code. **"It compiles"** doesn't mean a thing. The assembler will happily let you mix data and code and simply assemble that. It does not hold your hand. So what do you expect your code to do? How do you run it? Do you know the difference between running and "compiling"? Anyway, that is another question.